# Why does JavaScript not give any error for condition block after else?

Tags: javascript, interpreter

It may sound strange, but I unexpectedly put condition for else clause and Javascript did not give any error. Due this it took me some time to find the problem. Here is code.

```
    // no discount
    if(seo_price <= 0 && web_discount <= 0)
    {
        set_result_price(result_msg[0], total_price);
    }

    else if(seo_price > 0 && web_discount == 0)
    {
        msg = result_msg[0].concat(' ',result_msg[1],' ',result_msg[3]);
        set_result_price(msg, total_price * double_discount + seo_price, total_price + seo_price);
    }

    else if(seo_price == 0 && web_discount > 0)
    {
        msg = result_msg[0].concat(' ',result_msg[1],' ',result_msg[2]);
        set_result_price(msg, total_price * double_discount, total_price);
    }

    else(seo_price > 0 && web_discount > 0)
    {
        web_discount = total_price * ((100 - web_discount)/100) + seo_price;
        double_discount = total_price * double_discount + seo_price;
        
        if(web_discount < double_discount)
        {
            msg = result_msg[0].concat(' ',result_msg[1],' ',result_msg[2]);
            set_result_price(msg, web_discount, total_price + seo_price);
        }
        else
        {
            msg = result_msg[0].concat(' ',result_msg[1],' ',result_msg[3]);
            set_result_price(msg, double_discount, total_price + seo_price);
        }
    }
```

Why doesn't `else(seo_price > 0 && web_discount > 0)` throw an error?

If it is language convention and Javascript puts implicit semicolons by its own, then programming becomes impossible!

Comment: This line is wrong `else(seo_price > 0 && web_discount > 0)`

Comment: _"Due this it took me some time to find the problem"_ - So what's the question then?

Comment: I think this is a good question and it's not fair the question is closed. The explanation of Teemu is great as well. I like to start my opening curly braces on the same line like: https://jsfiddle.net/q6ofy3rt/. This will result in an error. When opening curly braces on a new line like: https://jsfiddle.net/q6ofy3rt/1/ it will not result in an error. Based on this you could say it's best practice to open curly braces on the same line.

Comment: I saw your edit to the question. To comment that edit, I'd say [ASI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion) doesn't make programming with JS impossible, it's a [standardized](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-rules-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion) feature, and when you know about it, you can live with it. It's arguable, if the feature is useful, though.

Comment: In your case, the lack of the error is due to the used indentation. I'd suggest you to use [OTBS variant of K&B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Variant:_1TBS_\(OTBS\)) when writing JS. It's the most adapted indentation style among the JS developers, and some gotchas (many of them related to ASI) in the language can be best avoided by using the said indentation style.

Comment: Problem is not that do not know JS rules. Problem is that I do not want to know this. Actually It is OK since I write just 10-20 lines of JS code in a month. But I do not understand people who use JS as main language. I see that whole back-end is written in JS. Fundamental languages such as C, PHP do not pay any attention to newline, tabs, whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

The incomplete `if .. else .. if` construction in your code doesn't throw an error, because it's valid JavaScript when using that particular indentation convention.

Any JS expression can occur on a line by its own, it's not necessary to store or otherwise use the result. When the opening curly brace is on its own line, JavaScript ASI (Automatic Semicolon Insertion) terminates the `else` after the orphanned expression, and the code block will be executed despite of the result of the `if .. else`.

It's notable, that `if` and `else` don't provide the use of the code block. If the block is omitted, only the next statement after the keyword is executed as a part of `if` and `else`. The next is perfectly valid JS:

```
if (x === true)
    doTrue();
else
    doFalse();

// Also a lonely else after if would be fine, the semicolon represents the empty statement
else;
```

What is happening in your code is the next:

```
if(seo_price == 0 && web_discount > 0)
{
    ...
}
else (seo_price > 0 && web_discount > 0);
{ ... } //                              ^-- A semicolon added by ASI
//                                          The former parenthed expression is valid JS
```

Comment: your answer do not explain why `else` is accepting `(seo_price > 0 && web_discount > 0)` condition.

Comment: No? "_Any JS expression can occur on a line by its own_" is the explanation. That expression (you call it condition, but it's just a couple of expressions enclosed within  parentehes, which is evaluated as a single expression) is similar to `'use strict';` It doesn't fire an error in older JS engines not supporting strict mode, because the string is just an expression, and is evaluated in older engines as it is, without the side effects the said string has in modern browsers.

Comment: @Fazliddin I've updated the answer, maybe it's more understandable now.

Comment: Though [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) says `if (condition) statement1 [else statement2]`, the statements here [can obviously be pure expressions too](https://jsfiddle.net/8q7dexL1/1/).